# can the functors called from algorithms acting on a map accept pair<K, V> instead of value_type?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, const-correctness

I tried to write a short function to invert an `std::map<K, V>` (I know about boost.bimap, this is for self-education), and found, to my surprise, that the code that GCC 4.4 accepted with -pedantic -ansi settings was rejected as const-incorrect by SunCC (5.8, from 2005).

Since `value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`, SunCC insisted that I const-qualify my `K` type in the arguments to functions that are passed to `transform()` and `for_each()`, and in the type of the return value to be passed to `std::inserter`, as far as I can tell, it might be right? Which compiler was standards-compliant?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
template<typename K, typename V>
std::pair<V, K> flip_pair(const std::pair<K, V>& p) // GCC/MSVC
//std::pair<const V, K> flip_pair(const std::pair<const K, V>& p) // SunCC
{
     return std::make_pair(p.second, p.first); // GCC/MSVC
//     return std::pair<const V, K>(p.second, p.first); // SunCC
}
template<typename K, typename V>
std::multimap<V, K> invert_map(const std::map<K, V>& in)
{
     std::multimap<V, K> out;
     transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::inserter(out, out.begin()),
               flip_pair<K, V>);
     return out;
}
void print_pair(const std::pair<int, std::string>& p) // GCC/MSVC
//void print_pair(const std::pair<const int, std::string>& p) // SunCC
{
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << '\n';
}
int main()
{
     std::map<std::string, int> map;
     map["foo"] = 1; map["bar"] = 2; map["baz"] = 3;
     std::multimap<int, std::string> revmap = invert_map(map);
     for_each(revmap.begin(), revmap.end(), print_pair);
}
```

Comment: Does that version of Sun's compiler support member template functions?  If not, that might explain the absence of implicit conversion constructors `template<typename A,typename B> template<typename C,typename D> std::pair<A,B>::pair(const std::pair<C,D>&);`.

Comment: @aschepler: That constructor is #defined out with _RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES on my system, it turns out. But the same program compiles with `-library=stlport4`, which picks up a different set of includes. The compiler itself is not to blame, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual C++ and g++ are correct; this code (with `flip_pair<K, V>()` taking a `const std::pair<K, V>&`) is okay.

Inside of `transform`, `flip_pair<K, V>` is being called.  Since the object being passed to that function is a `pair<const K, V>`, a temporary object of type `pair<K, V>` is created (`pair` has a converting constructor that allows you to convert one pair type to another if the `.first` and `.second` types are convertible).

This temporary is passed to `flip_pair<K, V>()`, taking advantage of the fact that a const reference can be bound to a temporary.

Comment: Doesn't creating a temporary `pair<K,V>` discard const qualifiers? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to just qualify the type as `pair<const K, V>` in those functions?

Comment: @JoshD, the compiler would not discard qualifiers in the type. And the types in flip_pair<K, V> would be: flip_pair<std::map<K, V>::value_type::first_type, std::map<K, V>::value_type::second_type> which would expand out to: flip_pair<const std::map<K, V>::key_type, std::map<K, V>::mapped_type>. In other words, K is const K in the instantiation of flip_pair in invert_map, so the additional const qualifier is unnecessary.

Comment: Simple as always! Forgot all about that constructor, confused by the 'wrong type while instantiating' errors.